# Synchronize Eclipse workspace automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

Windows support subscription to folder changing. Probably most other operating systems do.

Does Eclipse able to track filesystem changes automatically, without pressing refresh?

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

[image]

More information here -

- [**Bug 340977**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340977)

Comment: On newer versions of Eclipse the option is called `Refresh using native hooks or polling` (in the same place).